# Android share credential with my other application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I have an existing application A and I am developing new application B. I have some kind of access_token saved in sharePreference of Application A. And I would like to share that credential to application B. So the idea is there will be a buttton on Application A and when user click on it , it will open application B and the user will login automatically without going through login page. It

I have been reading about sharing sharePreference , Content Provider. I try to find how to access sharePreference using Content Provider but there are only tutorials on how to access sqllite database.

Is there any other way of sharing data privately between specific apps?

I really appreciate for any comment on this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to share preference among different apps.

For your specific use case, it is possible to share keys using android keychain API.

[More on keychain](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#WhichShouldIUse)